# SQL - show distinct weekdays based on date + loop thru corresponding records

Tags: mysql

I have list of contracts and i would like to select all distinct weekdays (so i need to convert date of the records to name of the weekdays and select distinct weekdays) and then display all the contracts that are corresponding to specific weekday ( so i need to convert the dates to weekdays  and then mach it with the previous selection).

Example Records:

1. C1 - 24.04.19 Wed
2. C2 - 01.05.19 Wed
3. C3 - 25.04.19 Thr
4. C4 - 23.04.19 Tue

And required listing:

```
TUE
- C4 
WED
- C1
- C2 
THR
- C3
```

Have no idea how to approach it in SQL. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d.%m.%y'), '%a') as date, contract
FROM dates
ORDER BY date
```

You will have following result:

```
date  contract
Thu,  C3
Tue,  C4
Wed,  C1
Wed,  C2
```

Comment: SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%a') as contract_weekday FROM cleaning ORDER BY contract_weekday DESC

Comment: so with this i got distinct weekdays from the table. now i have to print out all contract coresponding to these days

Comment: SELECT * FROM cleaning WHERE cleaningdate=DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%a') ORDER BY cleaningdate  ... something like this ... but is not coded well

Comment: SELECT * FROM cleaning WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%a')='$cleaningdate' ORDER BY cleaningdate

Comment: Thank you Yuriy Marad for helping me out

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want. In my example you will have an expected result, I mean all contracts corresponding to days. I guess you want to change output format?

Comment: No problem, Nita :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%a') as contract_weekday FROM cleaning ORDER BY contract_weekday DESC") or die(mysqli_error());
while($row1 = $result1->fetch_array())  {
echo $cleaningdate = $row1['contract_weekday'];

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cleaning WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cleaningdate, '%a')='$cleaningdate' ORDER BY cleaningdate") or die(mysqli_error()); 

} 
?>
```